# Working of Return statement in a method in Java

Tags: java, return-type

I am trying to understand the working of return statement in JAVA.

My doubt is if inside a method with a Non void return type, I have a decision block which also has a return statement of its own, Still I have to return some value .

For understanding here is a sample code I have written :-

```
public int bunnyEars(int bunnies) {

    //int count=0;
    if (bunnies >=1) {
        count = count + 2;
        bunnyEars(bunnies -1);

        return count1;
    }
    return count2 ;
}
```

In the mentioned code I just want to return the no. of bunnies which I am being able to do from inside the bunnyEars method count1. But still JAVA wont allow to have a  non-void method without a return type which is totally understood and I have to add count2 return also. Now I am suspecting that I am having a conceptual understanding failure here. Kindly let me know if I am missing something? Kindly let me know If I am missing some more info here.

[Edited] Full code:

```
public class Test5 {
    //public int ears=1;
    public int count=0;

    public int bunnyEars(int bunnies) {
        //int count=0;

        if (bunnies >=1) {
            count = count + 2;
            bunnyEars(bunnies -1);

            return count;
        }
        return count ;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test5 test5= new Test5();
        System.out.println(test5.bunnyEars(90));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your uncertainty? the method must return a value; it can't only return a value if some condition holds.

Comment: There are several problems with that code that your compiler will catch. You're asking for more information but your question isn't clear.

Comment: khelwood :- I understand the method should return a value which I completely understand. My point is that inside the if then statement I am returning the count1. Then why do I need to return something? That is where I feel I have some conceptual understanding missing. Do I really need two return types? cant I just use one return type to handle the situation. I feel two return types are redundant.

Comment: @Celeo: I ran the code on my eclipse .. It is runnign with all the main methods et al. 
`public class Test5 {
 //public int ears=1;
 public int count=0;
 
 public int bunnyEars(int bunnies) {
 
  //int count=0;
  if (bunnies >=1)
   {
   
   
   count = count + 2;
   bunnyEars(bunnies -1);
   
   return count;}
  
  return count ;
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
  Test5 test5= new Test5();
  System.out.println(test5.bunnyEars(90));
  
  
 }
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to return count2 which should be zero. Which means if there are no bunnies then there are no ears. So which returning you should be returning some value irrespective of the conditional block.

So in this case

```
return count1;
```

represents the number of ears if the bunnies are represent, while

```
return count2;
```

represents the number of ears when there are no bunnies, which should be 0.

I hope that gives you some clarification

Answer (score 0):

I think your conceptual misunderstanding lies with understanding the flow of the program.
Supposed you were to use this method by calling:

```
bunnyEars(2)
```

Then, once you enter the method, the first thing the program does is check if 3 >= 1. Since this is true, you proceed into the code inside the {..} (called a 'block').  Inside this block, you increment count by 2.  I am assuming count is defined elsewhere in the class, but suppose the current value for count is 10.  Then, the new value of count will be 12.

After this, the program executes the line:

```
bunnyEars(bunnies - 1)
```

Which translates to:

```
bunnyEars(1)
```

Now, basically, you are calling the same method again, but passing in 1 instead of 2.
Once again, the program checks to see that 1 >= 1, which is true.  So it goes into the
if-block which, again, increments count by 2.  So now, count = 14.  Then it calls the
same method again but this time passing in 0.

```
bunnyEars(0)
```

Since 0 >= 1 evaluates to false, you the program skips the if-block and continues
execution after the block.  So know, you are in the method bunnyEars(), but you have
completely skipped over your "return" statement.  But, alas, bunnyEars MUST return an int.
So this is why you must have a return after the block.  In your case, bunnyEars(0) returns count2 and the program-execution returns to where you called bunnyEars(0).

Read up on recursive calls.  The basic idea of a recursive method is that, inside the recursive method, you must have some case that terminates the recursion (otherwise you will loop forever).

For example, the following code will go on forever:

```
public int sum(int in)
{
    return in + sum(in - 1);
}
```

This will keep going on forever, because sum(1) will call sum(0) which calls sum(-1).
So, I must have a condition that terminates the recursion:

```
public int sum(int in)
{
   if(in == 0) return 0;
   return in + sum(in - 1);
}
```

Now, I have a terminating-case. So if I call sum(1), it will call sum(0) which returns 0. So my result is 1 + 0 = 1.

Similarily,

- sum(2) = 2 + sum(1) = 2 + 1 + sum(0) = 2 + 1 + 0
- sum(3) = 3 + sum(2) = 3 + 2 + sum(1) = 3 + 2 + 1 + sum(0) = 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 6

Hope this helps!

Comment: THANKS @goparkyourcar .. I did implement the recursive method on my own but what I was not understanding was that what the final count2 return is actually working as the else .. Initially I was thinking that even if the if part's return has done its job still the other return type will be fired(which now I am laughing at :-) ) .. Thanks for the elaborate expalnation. SO rox

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it, your question is why you still need to return count2 if you return count1. The answer is basically 'what happens if you don't enter the if block?'. In that case, without `return count2`, you wouldn't have a return value, which is what Java is complaining about. If you really don't want two return statements, you could probably do something like:

```
public int bunnyEars(int bunnies) {
    int count=0;
    if (bunnies >=1) {
        count = count + 2;
        bunnyEars(bunnies -1);
    }

    return count ;
}
```

On a side note, this and the code you posted in your question won't work for regression purposes, but the one in your comment does, and there it looks like you have a static variable for count, in which case you could set the return type to void and just print count.